# Locating similar points between two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Let's create some sample data

```
n = 1000;
data1 = Table[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 1, n}]
data2 = Table[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 1, n}]
```

As you can see, we have two data lists, `data1` and `data2` which contain six columns of real numbers. Let's call $x_i, y_i, z_i, p_{xi}, p_{yi}, p_{zi}$ the elements of `data1` and $x_j, y_j, z_j, p_{xj}, p_{yj}, p_{zj}$ the elements of `data2`.

My scope is to find if there are any identical points between the two lists and which are exactly these duplicate points. By the term "identical" I refer to points for which

$|x_i - x_j| < 10^{-5}$, 
$|z_i - z_j| < 10^{-5}$, 
$|p_{xi} - p_{xj}| < 10^{-5}$, 
$|p_{zi} - p_{zj}| < 10^{-5}$, simultaneously. Note that we are not interested about $y$ and $p_y$.

Any suggestions?

I use version 9.0 of MMA.

Comment: Note that `RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 6}]` will generate your fake data a bit more compactly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest). For example, with the data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list1 = RandomReal[1, {10^4, 4}];
list2 = RandomReal[1, {10^4, 4}];
```

You can define a [`NearestFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestFunction):

```
nf = Nearest[list1->"Index", DistanceFunction->ChessboardDistance];
```

[`ChessboardDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChessboardDistance) measures the distance between 2 points assuming the distance is covered by a Queen (or King). Now, with 10^4 random points it is extremely unlikely that any 2 points have a [`ChessboardDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChessboardDistance) of 10^-5 or less. For the above data, a distance that produces "identical" points is something on the order of 10^-2:

```
res = nf[list2, {All, 10^-2}];
identical = Pick[list2, Length /@ res, Except[0, _Integer]]
```

> {{0.685292, 0.397605, 0.475159, 0.328691}, {0.335736, 0.280756, 0.407469, 
>     0.533887}, {0.912073, 0.685974, 0.952897, 0.271151}, {0.326838, 0.504337, 
>     0.125602, 0.314291}, {0.676946, 0.110687, 0.939404, 0.492283}, {0.747907, 
>     0.385783, 0.230076, 0.198834}, {0.440763, 0.351743, 0.492735, 
>     0.207811}, {0.539763, 0.309531, 0.115746, 0.700582}, {0.935517, 0.227098, 
>     0.640445, 0.400848}, {0.400585, 0.0229188, 0.652013, 0.652141}, {0.335365, 
>     0.111325, 0.664795, 0.17639}, {0.43019, 0.163319, 0.075704, 
>     0.67404}, {0.661021, 0.03022, 0.20255, 0.372881}}

Let's compare the identical elements:

```
Thread[{list1[[#]]& /@ DeleteCases[res, {}], identical}]
```

> {{{{0.689472, 0.40506, 0.473408, 0.332559}}, {0.685292, 0.397605, 0.475159, 
>      0.328691}}, {{{0.342825, 0.276343, 0.408599, 0.525442}}, {0.335736, 
>      0.280756, 0.407469, 
>      0.533887}}, {{{0.902177, 0.68945, 0.94329, 0.265362}}, {0.912073, 0.685974,
>       0.952897, 
>      0.271151}}, {{{0.323412, 0.510421, 0.121472, 0.317904}}, {0.326838, 
>      0.504337, 0.125602, 
>      0.314291}}, {{{0.679234, 0.120186, 0.933942, 0.490366}}, {0.676946, 
>      0.110687, 0.939404, 
>      0.492283}}, {{{0.748489, 0.393792, 0.232312, 0.198016}}, {0.747907, 
>      0.385783, 0.230076, 
>      0.198834}}, {{{0.447516, 0.350137, 0.49212, 0.211425}}, {0.440763, 
>      0.351743, 0.492735, 
>      0.207811}}, {{{0.549304, 0.318568, 0.108417, 0.702578}}, {0.539763, 
>      0.309531, 0.115746, 
>      0.700582}}, {{{0.93924, 0.224546, 0.635966, 0.398112}}, {0.935517, 
>      0.227098, 0.640445, 
>      0.400848}}, {{{0.409333, 0.0203513, 0.644093, 0.654824}}, {0.400585, 
>      0.0229188, 0.652013, 
>      0.652141}}, {{{0.342227, 0.111995, 0.663345, 0.178174}}, {0.335365, 
>      0.111325, 0.664795, 
>      0.17639}}, {{{0.424369, 0.157971, 0.0763675, 0.678569}}, {0.43019, 
>      0.163319, 0.075704, 
>      0.67404}}, {{{0.663532, 0.0398141, 0.193906, 0.369557}}, {0.661021, 
>      0.03022, 0.20255, 0.372881}}}

Looks identical based on the distance measure `.01`.

Comment: When I evaluate `nf` I get the following error: Nearest::near1: "\!\({{0.8173894901710712`, 0.11141961113123644`, 0.7895259946338515`, 0.18780314670602638`}, {0.24136096745765045`, 0.06573875950878105`, 0.5422466205096241`, 0.23115450673602744`}, {0.3960060815485871`, 0.7004737819422449`, 0.21182597905412748`, 0.748656881482948`}, <<46>>, {0.17990176055342078`, 0.035655750518962304`, 0.2653318875513011`, 0.8421484523408236`}, <<9950>>} -> \"Index\"\) is neither a list of real points nor a valid list of rules" Note that I use version 9.

Comment: In version 9 use `Nearest[list->Automatic, DistanceFunction->ChessboardDistance]`, but this will be very slow. Non-default `DistanceFunction` specifications in M9 are slow, but in M10 they are just as fast as the default. I recommend trying to upgrade to at least M10.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

First, define the matching condition:

```
matchQ[point1_List, point2_List, threshold_] := 
  Abs[Part[point1, 1] - Part[point2, 1]] < threshold && 
   Abs[Part[point1, 3] - Part[point2, 3]] < threshold && 
   Abs[Part[point1, 4] - Part[point2, 4]] < threshold && 
   Abs[Part[point1, 6] - Part[point2, 6]] < threshold;
```

Then you can use the following function to take cross product of the two lists and then select those pair of 6-tuples that match matchQ.

```
IdenticalList[l1_List, l2_List,threshold_] := 
  Select[Tuples[{l1, l2}], matchQ[#[[1]], #[[2]],threshold] &];
```

Your example:

```
IdenticalList[data1,data2,10^(-5)]
```

Comment: It seems that when the lists contain a large number of data (try n = 10000) the code aborts due to insufficient memory ... General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation. Is there any trick to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I cannot see any way but to check all the $n^2$ pairs by brute force.

Comment: What exactly do you propose? Could you please explain the "brute force" approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to know IF there are duplicates according to your criteria, but it seems that you do not want to know which are the "duplicates", I would use `DuplicateFreeQ` on a new list generated from removing duplicates from each of the original ones, then joining the two resulting lists. You also need an appropriate distance/test function that embodies your criteria.

`DuplicateFreeQ` was introduced after v.9; nevertheless, its functionality is equivalent to:

```
DuplicateFreeQ[list] --> SameQ[list, DeleteDuplicates[list]]
```

and `DeleteDuplicates` takes a test function to decide whether two elements are to be considered the same.

So here we go. `withintolerance` is the pairwise test function to test whether two points are within your specified tolerance and should be considered the same. `duplicatefreeq` reproduces the functionality of the built in `DuplicateFreeQ` for older versions.

```
Clear[withintolerance, duplicatefreeq]

withintolerance[a_, b_] := And @@ 
     Thread[Abs@*Subtract @@@ (Transpose[{a, b}][[{1, 3, 4, 6}]]) < 1*^-5]

duplicatefreeq[list_] := SameQ[list, DeleteDuplicates[list, withintolerance]]
```

Let's generate some data:

```
data1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 6}];
data2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 6}];

duplicatefreeq[
  Join @@ (DeleteDuplicates[#, withintolerance] & /@ {data1, data2})
]
(* False *)
```

This indicates that, indeed, there are values that are considered equal according to your criteria.

---

To **list the duplicated points**, you can still use the `withintolerance` function and the combined list generated above, then use Tally to count the frequency of each point, and select those that appear more than once in the combined list.

```
Join @@ (DeleteDuplicates[#, withintolerance] & /@ {data1, data2});
Cases[Tally[%, withintolerance], {l_List, n_} /; n > 1 :> l]

(* Out: {{-0.966795,-0.666258,0.596014,-0.558378,-0.814469,-0.585457},<<37>>,{<<1>>}} *)
```

Comment: Actually, I do want to know which are the duplicates!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Well, you probably want to adjust your question then, because you asked "IF" there are duplicates. Do you want a function that returns each duplicate value then?

Comment: See my edit. Yes, I want a function returning all the duplicate points within the tolerance.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Take a look at my addition at the end of the answer. Would that work?

Comment: I tested it to my actual data and the results are not correct. The reported duplicates have common x but the values of z, p_x and p_z are not equal (their differences are much higher than the tolerance).

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Could you share a snippet of the actual data?